# Windows 8 metro split screen on lower resolution (1,280 x 1,024)

Tags: windows, windows-8

After researching elsewhere, I have found that I seem to have a high enough resolution to run windows 8 (I am using it right now) and all of the metro apps, but some features (mainly split screen for [metro] apps) simply don't work. Does anyone know of a program/code to get around this? I only have a basic knowledge of computers, so please correct me if I am missing out on something...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For what it's worth, at this point you should probably install Windows 10 instead. It's a free upgrade, and removes most of the resolution restrictions. Windows 10 can run "metro" apps in windows on the desktop, or can snap them, as you prefer. While I haven't tried it on such a low-resolution display, it should support side-by-side "metro" apps even in snapped (tablet) mode. In desktop window mode, you can just use Aero Snap (as since Win7) to snap your windows - "metro" or normal desktop windows - to the edges of the screen.

Answer (score 4):

Your setup is the minimum resolution to run Windows 8, but not the minimum resolution to run applications side-by-side (snapped).  This is by design and I doubt there is a way around it, other than to increase your screen resolution to the minimum specs.

The following quote is from an [MS development blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20151201195134/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/b8/archive/2012/03/21/scaling-to-different-screens.aspx):

> #### Minimum resolution and snap
>
> The resolution that supports all the features of Windows 8, including
> multitasking with snap, is 1366x768. We chose this resolution as it
> has enough horizontal pixels to fit the 320px width of a snapped app,
> next to a main app with a 1024px width. The specs of the Samsung
> tablet that we unveiled at the //build/ conference are 11.6-inches
> with a 1366x768 resolution (the Samsung Series 7 tablet in market
> today). These specs are the minimum screen resolution that supports
> all the features of Windows 8 on a useful physical size.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just to clear up: there are no mods/etc. that can enable split screen apps on my resolution, right?

Comment: @Alexander - The most straightforward path would be to upgrade your graphics hardware. However, if you are on a laptop, that may not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Snapped view (and thus filled as well) I only enabled system-wide for 1366 horizontal resolution or higher. So on a 1280 device it's not enabled for any apps, and there isn't a way to change this behavior. It's intended to keep the minimum size in filled view at least 1024x768.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Just to clear up: there are no mods/etc. that can enable split screen apps on my resolution, right?

Comment: Some display drivers support a "virtual resolution" feature that allows you to pretend you have more bits on the screen than you actually have. I have no idea if this will work though.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio simulator will enable you to simulate 1366x768 resolution (and higher).  You can test snap using that.  Here's an article which [introduces the simulator](https://web.archive.org/web/20160121045627/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/09/29/first-look-at-windows-simulator.aspx) and can show you the proper button to push if you have issues finding it (see the "Multiple screen Resolutions" section).

Answer (score 0):

Try download windows Blue, that just like windows 8 but there is fix with metro apps, and snap on low resolution

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Here at Superuser, we pride ourselves on answers that provide enough detail to solve the question, could you please expand on your answer and explain both what windows blue it, where to get it, and how to apply the fix?